# Error with Google Assistant SDK 0.2.0 release

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

I'm getting the following error on the Raspberry Pi 3 with the new 0.2.0 release. After I say "Ok Google", it shows `ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED`. Then a few seconds after I make the query, the error shows.

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ google-assistant-demo
ON_MUTED_CHANGED:
  {'is_muted': False}
ON_START_FINISHED

ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED
[2433:2444:ERROR:speech_processing_task.cc(340)] S3 connection has timed out: No data from S3
ON_ASSISTANT_ERROR:
  {'is_fatal': False}
[2433:2444:ERROR:assistant_output_handler.cc(589)] Failed with a general speech recognition error
ON_RESPONDING_STARTED:
  {'is_error_response': True}
Segmentation fault
```

[Update] I am using a shared WiFi network from my laptop to Raspberry's Ethernet. I can access it via ssh and normally install packages, ping websites etc.

Comment: This could be a connection error. Mind checking if your device has network connectivity?

Comment: @AlfonsoGomezJordanaManas I am using a shared WiFi network from my laptop to Raspberry's Ethernet. I can access it via ssh and normally install packages, ping websites etc.

Comment: Thank you for the info Giovanni. I'm from the Assistant SDK team, and we are looking into this issue. Will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error:

```
ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED
[1482:1493:ERROR:speech_processing_task.cc(646)] Detected communication error: Downstream closed prematurely.
ON_ASSISTANT_ERROR:
  {'is_fatal': False}
[1482:1493:ERROR:assistant_output_handler.cc(589)] Failed with a general speech recognition error
ON_RESPONDING_STARTED:
  {'is_error_response': True}
ON_RESPONDING_FINISHED
ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_FINISHED:
  {'with_follow_on_turn': False}
```

I was able to resolve it by enbabling the API for my project (make sure you click the blue play button at top of screen), here are the instructions from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/config-dev-project-and-account):

> 2. Enable the Google Assistant API on the project you selected (see the Terms of Service).
>
> ENABLE THE API
>
> Click Enable.